# Backup big size database time out error in SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database

I try to backup my database but I get an error:

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>   The backup or restore was aborted.

This is my code, and my database is up to 20GB in size.

```
string query = "Backup database Testing to disk='C:\Test.bak'"
con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

How can I change a timeout value in C# or query?

Comment: surely a quick google search would show something?

Comment: RTFM. I mean, seriously, there is a property on SqlCommand. It is so hidden, it is even named "CommandTimeout".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use **CommandTimeout property** ([Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), 0 means no limit.

Add

> cmd.CommandTimeout = 0

to your code:

```
string query = "Backup database Testing to disk='C:\Test.bak'"
con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: what is 0 ? 0 is no limit?

Comment: Yes. Edited answer to make it clearer