# 'Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.'

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I want to restore database from selected drive but each time it throws the following exception

> Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

But this is only for a specific database when I tried to restore another one then its worked perfectly.
Can anyone help me out please.
Following code I have used

```cs
openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
query("IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = '" + cmbDatabaseName.Text + "') DROP DATABASE " + cmbDatabaseName.Text + " RESTORE DATABASE " + cmbDatabaseName.Text + " FROM DISK = '" + openFileDialog1.FileName + "'");
lbmsg.Visible = true;
lbmsg.Text = "Database Backup file has been restore successfully";
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Backup big size database time out error in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932806/backup-big-size-database-time-out-error-in-sql-server)

Comment: Why are you dropping the database before restoring? You gain *nothing* by this, but if anything goes wrong you'll lose your data. This may be what's blocking the call too - a `DROP DATABASE` can't proceed if there are any other connections open. Simply remove the `IF ... DROP database` statement completely

Answer (score 0):

You problem is DROP DATABASE because there must be some connections to it.
Put this command into your code: ALTER DATABASE

```
query("    
            IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = '" + cmbDatabaseName.Text + "'); 
            ALTER DATABASE " + cmbDatabaseName.Text + " SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
            DROP DATABASE " + cmbDatabaseName.Text + "; 
            RESTORE DATABASE " + cmbDatabaseName.Text + " FROM DISK = '" + openFileDialog1.FileName + "';
");
```

Comment: I tried above solution but now i got following exception   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
Changes to the state or options of database 'dbExpressPOS' cannot be made at this time. The database is in single-user mode, and a user is currently connected to it.'

Comment: If database is switched to SINGLE_USER mode then you cannot use it from any other sessions. By a sysadmin user turn it back to MULTI_USER: